# Set height from another element via css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have two `divs` per row. The second `div` should always display its full content. The height of the first `div` should always be the same as the height of the second `div` from the same row. If the height of the first div is not enough to display its content, it should be scrollable.

I set the height of the first div by using javascript but I guess it is not the best solution because the content of the first and the second divs can be changed. So this javascript function will be called a lot of times. Is it possible to get this effect by using css?

My code is:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <style>
            .firstElementClass, .secondElementClass{
                float:left;
                width: 30%;
                text-align: center;
            }   
            .firstElementClass{
                background: red;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            .secondElementClass{
                background: yellow;
            }
            .rowClass{
                margin-top: 20px;
                clear:both;
                padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="rowClass">
            <div class="firstElementClass">11aa<br>11aa<br>11aa<br>11aa<br>11aa<br>11aa</div>
            <div class="secondElementClass">11bb<br>11bb<br>11bb<br>11bb</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowClass">
            <div class="firstElementClass">AA</div>
            <div class="secondElementClass">22bb<br>22bb<br></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowClass">
            <div class="firstElementClass">AA</div>
            <div class="secondElementClass">33bb<br>33bb<br>33bb<br>33bb</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowClass">
            <div class="firstElementClass">AA</div>
            <div class="secondElementClass">44bb<br>44bb<br>44bb</div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(".firstElementClass").each(function(){
                $(this).height($($(this).parent().find(".secondElementClass")[0]).height());
            });
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Does the height of the 2nd `div` keep changing? or is it fixed?

Comment: If that is the case, then you can have a `max-height` set to the height of the 2nd div's max, say `72px or something` inside the class selector for  `.firstElementClass, .secondElementClass` I can't really think of any other option other than using JS if you want to dynamically alter the height property.

Comment: You could've used Vanilla JavaScript for this instead of using jQuery because jQuery has an overhead because the jQuery is first converted to vanilla JS, so maybe just use that instead?

Comment: yes, the heights will change so your solution will not work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `float`, you should use some kind of tabular layout here, either [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or `display: table`.

This gives you rows where all the divs have the same height (the height of the tallest div in the row). Now, to adjust everything by the *last* div, you can use `position: absolute` on the *contents* of the *first* div, which means it will take whatever space is left after all the other layout has been arranged (notice the extra `.cellValue` divs inside `.firstElementClass` in the example below).

```css
.myTable {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 20px;
    width: 60%;
}
.rowClass {
    display: table-row;
}
.firstElementClass,
.secondElementClass {
    display: table-cell;
}

.firstElementClass {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
}
.firstElementClass .cellValue {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.secondElementClass {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="myTable">
    <div class="rowClass">
        <div class="firstElementClass">
            <div class="cellValue">11aa<br>11aa<br>11aa<br>11aa<br>11aa<br>11aa</div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondElementClass">
            <div class="cellValue">11bb<br>11bb<br>11bb<br>11bb</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowClass">
        <div class="firstElementClass">
            <div class="cellValue">AA</div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondElementClass">
            <div class="cellValue">22bb<br>22bb<br></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowClass">
        <div class="firstElementClass">
            <div class="cellValue">AA</div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondElementClass">
            <div class="cellValue">33bb<br>33bb<br>33bb<br>33bb</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowClass">
        <div class="firstElementClass">
            <div class="cellValue">AA</div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondElementClass">
            <div class="cellValue">44bb<br>44bb<br>44bb</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

With **flexbox** you can achieve two divs to be the same height

```
.rowClass{
display:flex;
}
.firstEl,.secondEl{
flex:1;}
```

if this is not what you're looking for let me know inthe comments.

Comment: I think it does not live up to the requirements. The height will be set to the highest div instead of the second one.

Comment: Well there are only 2 divs in the .rowClass elem, so I don't see how that's a problem

Comment: he said **The second div should always display its full content**  and **The height of the first div should always be the same as the height of the second div** so flex is gonna be a solution, Because second div gonna be always bigger than first 1 and he wants the first to match the second.